# Having issue with an application that generates a report in background instead on front

Tags: ms-access

I have an application built with Microsoft Access that generates reports.

Each time when the application runs, a mdb file is created (see the picture below).

The report is showing in background, I like that the report shows in the front.

When I close the application and delete the mdb file and run the application, the report shows in the front, but this is not the best solution can you please explain  why this is happening and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance

[image: Click please to see the image]

Comment: It's completely unclear what you mean by "report", and what it has to do with the .mdb

Comment: The application generate financial reports, the user choose the year and select among the options then the user click to print to display a report. the application is created with access and each time when the report is displayed an mdb file is created in the located file in the picture in my post.

Comment: thank you for your feedback i hope this time i was more clear and sorry for my bad english